# Combine multiindex columns with duplicate names

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

I have this multiindex dataframe:

[image]

I am trying to merge both columns named `MODIS.NDVI` under one same multi-index where the index `MODIS.NDVI` would return its corresponding p10, p25, p50, mean and std. Calling `df.xs('MODIS.NDVI', axis=1)` returns the expected output, so my questions are:

- How to reformat the df to remove unnecessary duplicate column names at `level=0`?
- Is that even necessary beyond a simple aesthetics concern since `.xs` permits that? Are there any risk of index "confusion" if duplicate names exist?

Comment: just a guess since we do not have a testable example: does `df.sort_index(axis=1)` work?

Comment: Post code to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @anky_91 Well done - that does the job, thanks! Sorry for the absence of testable example - my df is big and I am still very confused on how to make them for multi-index df. By attempting to create one, I realised that even use of .loc cleans everything, so I guess it the answer to my question was that it is just an aesthetics problem. If you add your answer I will gladly vote it up.

Comment: No problem..I believe this has been asked before (*cannot find it now since I am at work*)hence you can post it as an answer yourself :)